# How does one fire short staples into hard wood?

Tags: fastener

I find myself caught in the middle here.

My old electric staple gun will fire 1/4" staples but it's not capable of fully setting them because part of the target is some pretty hard wood.  The shortest staples I can find for my pneumatic gun are 1/2" and would go clear through and stick out the front.

Is there an answer or do I simply replace the tape the last guy to tackle this used?

Comment: *"How often have I said to you that when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?"* - [The Sign of the Four (1890)](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes#The_Sign_of_the_Four_.281890.29)

Comment: What's the application?

Comment: @gregmac I'm trying to fasten a piece of cardboard backing to a wooden frame.

Comment: Could you glue it?

Comment: @Steven I probably could.  It just seems strange that I can't find a way of stapling it.

Comment: Can you just hammer the staples after shooting them?

Answer (score 2):

Use 1/4" **Cut Tacks** instead: ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009IJA6VC))

[image]

Comment: And a needle nose pliers to hold them in just the right place when you take the first whack at each with your hammer.